# How to fix div shift from surrounding div that have width change from mouse hover?

Tags: html, css

I'm recreating my website thanks to some feedback from my community. On one of my pages: I have a section, within that section I have a div, within that div I got 6 to 7 more div. Those 6 to 7 change width when you hover over them with your mouse. They float left and the columns and rows vary based on screen size. The issue I have is when you hover over the first one in the first column everything below it shifts instead of slides like the last one in the first row. 
Website/page that is giving me trouble: https://www.blizzardcraft.net/tutorials

By following the code below the following occurs:

when you hover over box1 -> boxes 4 and after shift right

when you hover over box2 -> boxes 4 and after shift right

when you hover over box3 -> all just slightly shift down (Desired result)

I am unable to find the reason why the desired result only happens on one. I sadly do not know why the desired result even occurs as there is no different code from the rest (that I know of)

I have tried different paddings, float arrangements, and messing with overflow. (I have taken classes in high school about web development but complex html, css is still a little beyond my abilities at this present time and I do not know exactly what does what)

I hope someone here as an idea, I found many solutions on here before so I decided to post my question here.
This is my first post on here and I hope I did it right.

CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#select {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#boxes {
  margin: 20px;
}
#boxes .box {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #7f7f7f;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 27%;
  padding: 10px;

  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
}
#boxes .box:hover {
  width: 30%;
}
#boxes .box img {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  width: 100%;
}
#boxes .box h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
#boxes .box a, a:active, a:visited, a:hover, a:link {
  color: inherit;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<section id="boxes">
      <div class="container">
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="Box1.png" alt="Box1">
            <h3>Lobby</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="Box2.png" alt="Box2">
            <h3>Missile Wars</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="Box3.png" alt="Box3">
            <h3>Creative</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="" alt="Box4">
            <h3>Sky Block</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="" alt="Box5">
            <h3>BedrockSMP</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="" alt="Box6">
            <h3>TNT Wars</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Use a transform instead of changing the width, that way you keep the underlying layout as well as avoid a repaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Here is a take on your code using transition on the flex-basis property of the children elements: https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/BaBvaxr?editors=1100

```
<section id="boxes">
  <div class="container">
    <a>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://www.blizzardcraft.net/tutorials/media/images/Lobby.png" alt="Box1">
        <h3>Lobby</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://www.blizzardcraft.net/tutorials/media/images/Lobby.png" alt="Box2">
        <h3>Missile Wars</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://www.blizzardcraft.net/tutorials/media/images/Lobby.png" alt="Box3">
        <h3>Creative</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://www.blizzardcraft.net/tutorials/media/images/Lobby.png" alt="Box4">
        <h3>Sky Block</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://www.blizzardcraft.net/tutorials/media/images/Lobby.png" alt="Box5">
        <h3>BedrockSMP</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://www.blizzardcraft.net/tutorials/media/images/Lobby.png" alt="Box6">
        <h3>TNT Wars</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
}
#select {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #ffffff;
  /* FLEXBOX */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
#boxes a {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  transition: flex-basis 400ms ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#boxes a:hover {
  flex-basis: 33%;
}
#boxes {
  margin: 20px;
}
#boxes .box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #7f7f7f;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
}
#boxes .box img {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  width: 100%;
}
#boxes .box h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
#boxes .box a, a:active, a:visited, a:hover, a:link {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for reading and taking the time to help me out!

Comment: You're welcome @Matthew. Glad to be of help to you as others have been to me on my issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try separating your elements into "rows" using your container class. So your new code would look like this:

```
    <section id="boxes">
      <div class="container">
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="Box1.png" alt="Box1">
            <h3>Lobby</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="Box2.png" alt="Box2">
            <h3>Missile Wars</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="Box3.png" alt="Box3">
            <h3>Creative</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div classs="container">
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="" alt="Box4">
            <h3>Sky Block</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="" alt="Box5">
            <h3>BedrockSMP</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="" alt="Box6">
            <h3>TNT Wars</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
```

This stops the top 3 from interfering with the bottom three.

OR you could change your CSS to use the [transform property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) instead

Comment: Thank you for helping. Yours did solve my problem but I will be using @KostasX for my situation. I do have an idea for this to be used to clean up another page of mine. Thanks for taking the time to help me out.